# Vanilla JS image slideshow play/pause button

Tags: javascript

My play/pause button works the first time I press pause and the first time I press play. But after that if I want to pause the slideshow again, it just plays the slideshow at a faster speed and I am no longer able to pause it.

I am thinking maybe it is to do with the fact I have two separate functions: one for the play/pause button icon toggle, and another for the actual play pause behaviour? ****(update: this has now been fixed, but still doesn't work)****

Sorry, I am struggling with javascript, I have a lot to learn.

My script:

```
const playPause = document.querySelector('.pause');
let slideId;

// FUNCTION TO MOVE TO NEXT SLIDE
const moveToNextSlide = () => {
    slides = getSlides();
    if (index >= slides.length - 1) return;
    index++;
    slideGroup.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth * index}px)`;
    slideGroup.style.transition = '.8s';
}

// FUNCTION TO START SLIDESHOW
const startSlide = () => {
    slideId = setInterval(() => {
        moveToNextSlide();
    }, interval);
    playing = true;
};

// START AUTOMATIC SLIDESHOW UPON ENTERING THE PAGE
startSlide();

//PLAY PAUSE BUTTON - slideshow start/stop
playPause.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(!slideId) {
        slideId = startSlide();
        console.log('started');
    } else {
        clearInterval(slideId);
        slideId = null;
        console.log('stopped');
    }
});

//PLAY PAUSE BUTTON - image change
function toggle(button) {
    if (button.className != 'pause') {
        button.src = 'img/pause.png';
        button.className = 'pause';
    }
    else if (button.className == 'pause') {
        button.src = 'img/play.png';
        button.className = 'play';
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='image' src='img/pause.png' class='pause' onclick='toggle(this);' />
```

This is what the console looks like when I try to pause the slideshow for a second time:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some details in your code that are missing and would be helpful to have, but I guess that you can get rid of the `onclick` handler and attach two event listeners:

```js
let slideId;

// FUNCTION TO START SLIDESHOW
const startSlide = () => {
    let interval = 2000; // using just as sample
    playing = true;
    return setInterval(() => {
        console.log('moveToNextSlide();') // replaced just to test without missing code
    }, interval);
};

//PLAY PAUSE BUTTON - slideshow start/stop
playPause.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(!slideId) {
        slideId = startSlide();
        console.log('started');
    } else {
        clearInterval(slideId);
        slideId = null;
        console.log('stopped');
    }
});

//PLAY PAUSE BUTTON - image change
playPause.addEventListener('click', function toggle() { // the arrow function would not work in this case
    var button = this;
    if (button.className != 'pause') {
        button.src = 'img/pause.png';
        button.className = 'pause';
    }
    else if (button.className == 'pause') {
        button.src = 'img/play.png';
        button.className = 'play';
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense to have them both as event listeners. The slideshow is still not playing/pausing correctly though after the first time. I have edited my original question to include more code and added a screenshot of the console incase that's useful.

Comment: I updated my answer: you're not returning the `slideId` value

Comment: It worked, thanks. But I'm not fully understanding why it needed to be returned even after reading up on functions and how the return statement works. Initially the slideshow automatic play worked even without returning slideId. It the reason it has to be returned now because slideId is being used on its own in a separate function (the event listener)? Sorry if I am way off the mark.